# Buffer to String

Tags: java, android, string

I send/receive data between Android and other device through the usb.

The code that I use for receive data:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

int i = 0;
int s = buffer[0];
for (; i < s;  i++) {

    stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf((char)buffer[i]));                    
}

byte[] b = String.valueOf(stringBuilder).getBytes();
```

I receive fine all of bytes, except when the byte is bigger than 127. How to do?

I try to use:

```
stringBuilder2.append(String.valueOf((int)buffer[i] & 0xFF));
```

And work fine if I read String.valueOf(stringBuilder), but not when I create byte[]

Comment: `Data are a serie of bytes: byte[1,2,8,56,87,256]` — That's not a series of bytes. It's got 256 in it.

Comment: Srry, I never played with bytes.. ;)

Comment: Some characters are represented using multiple bytes so you need to be careful not to convert 1 byte at a time.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Your question consists of a lot of strange elements; and **seriously**: the ranges for java primitive types, that is **super basic stuff**. Meaning: when you start **playing** with something, then heck: understand what that means. Instead of putting up such a *mess* of a question.

Comment: If the byte stream is encoded text, then you have to know which character encoding the sender used. If it's not, then you can't convert it to a text datatype (String). Please [edit] to give details.

Answer (score 0):

If all the bytes you're receiving are in format ASCII, in your `stringBuilder` you already have the text of the String you need.

On the other side assuming that `buffer[0]` is the size of your buffer you could try something like this:

```
byte[] tmp = new byte[buffer[0]];
System.arraycopy(buffer, 1, tmp, 0, buffer[0]);
String result = new String(tmp);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I need an array of any value. The String for exaple is: 12358478512, and I need an array like: [12,358,4,78,5,12]

Comment: @Phyron Is it true that each time you receive a `buffer` inside there is a list of bytes that represents only one number?

Comment: In my code (first post), "byte[] b" contain a list of numbers. any position is one number. The problem is with the biggest numbers than 127

Comment: @Phyron In your example you have a numbers like `358` or `256` but in an unsigned byte the maximum number you can store is `255`. So it is not clear when a number stored in the array starts and finish. On the other hand, if you say that each byte is an number (0-255) and your example is wrong...